# How to format number with the mixing of (K) and Million(M) with intl package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, number-formatting

I want to show the number format with the mixing of **K** and **M**.
Example, for the number value ***5000,000***, want to show **0.5M** and for the value of **10000000** as **1M** . How to do like that as the example image?

[image]

Here is my number format snippet for the **primaryYAxis** of the column-chart.

```
NumericAxis(numberFormat: NumberFormat.compact())
```

Comment: You should use customised function to compact the value like `'{number / 500000}M'`

Comment: Yep... Now I did like that. This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are close you just nee to add

```
format.format(number);
```

Here's an example function:

```
String formatNumber(int number) {
  final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.compact();
  return format.format(number);
}

// Example usage
print(formatNumber(500000)); // Output: 500k
print(formatNumber(1000000)); // Output: 1M
print(formatNumber(1500000)); // Output: 1.5M
print(formatNumber(2000000)); // Output: 2M
```

Comment: No. I want to show **0.5M** instead of **500K**.